# Enum me retornando null pointer

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, enums

Meu Enum está retornando Null Pointer ao relizar essa call:

```
  System.out.println(DefinicaoSCM.getDefinicaoSCMPorDisciplina(Disciplina.IMPLEMENTACAO));
```

Implementação:

```
public enum DefinicaoSCM
{
   DESCONHECIDO(null, "NA", "NA"),
   IMPLANTACAO(Disciplina.IMPLANTACAO, "ipl_", "/Implantacao"),
   IMPLEMENTACAO(Disciplina.IMPLEMENTACAO, "imp_", "/Implementacao", "/Documentacao", "/Implantacao"),
   INTERFACE_GRAFICA(Disciplina.INTERFACE_GRAFICA, "ifg_", "/Design"),
   PROJETO(Disciplina.PROJETO, "prj_", "/Projeto"),
   REQUISITO(Disciplina.REQUISITO, "req_", "/Requisitos"),
   TESTE(Disciplina.TESTE, "tst_", "/Teste");

   private static Map<Disciplina, DefinicaoSCM> definicaoSCMPorDisciplina;
   private Disciplina disciplina;



   public static DefinicaoSCM getDefinicaoSCMPorDisciplina(Disciplina disciplina)
   {
      return definicaoSCMPorDisciplina.get(disciplina);
   }
```

Comment: `definicaoSCMPorDisciplina` não está instanciado.

Comment: Pode postar o seu código inteiro dessa classe? Em especial gostaria de saber do construtor e como o `definicaoSCMPorDisciplina` é instanciado e populado.

Comment: Apesar de não ter o código completo, já tive problemas em usar um Map num Enum antes. Sugiro tentar com um ImmutableMap do Guava. Vou procurar o que eu fiz pra resolver e posto o código depois.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para utilizar um Map em um Enum, só consegui utilizando o [ImmutableMap](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained) do [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava), no seu exemplo, ficaria como abaixo:

```
private static final Map<Disciplina, DefinicaoSCM> definicaoSCMPorDisciplina = ImmutableMap.<Disciplina, DefinicaoSCM>builder()
                    .put(Disciplina.IMPLANTACAO, new DefinicaoSCM())
                    .put(Disciplina.INTERFACE_GRAFICA, new DefinicaoSCM())
                    .put(Disciplina.PROJETO, new DefinicaoSCM())
                    .put(Disciplina.REQUISITO, new DefinicaoSCM())
                    .put(Disciplina.TESTE, new DefinicaoSCM())
                    .build();
```

O acesso ao Map continua da mesma maneira `.get(key)`.

Comment: Caracas, muito bom! Muito obrigado meu amigo!